# Arabic fonts issue in docker container for windowss

Tags: docker

I am using selectpdf utility to convert html to pdf which is working fine on windows host with english and arabic. i have converted the same into docker container. here the problem is english is working fine and arabic is displaying boxes. even fonts are not rendering properly in the pdf file.

Note : we are using windows container.